# Program runs under Keil uVision but not under STM32CubeIDE

Tags: c, timer, stm32, keil, stm32cubeide

I have a small program running on stm32wb55.  It tests the TIM2 timer with a delay function called `wait_us()`.  The program runs correctly when I compile it with Keil uVision 5, but when I compile it with STM32CubeIDE it gets stuck in the function `get_us()`.  Is there a bug in STM32CubeIDE?

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
extern void initialize_tim2(void);
extern void wait_us(volatile uint32_t us);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

/* Configure the peripherals common clocks */
  PeriphCommonClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  initialize_tim2();
  TIM2->CR1 |= 0x0001;
  wait_us(10);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LD1_Pin);
    HAL_Delay(500);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

```
#include "stm32wbxx.h"

volatile uint32_t tim2_counter;

void initialize_tim2(void)
{
  RCC->APB1ENR1 |= 0x00000001;
  TIM2->CR1 = 0x0004;
  TIM2->CR2 = 0x0000;
  TIM2->PSC = 0;
  TIM2->ARR = 32;
  TIM2->DIER = 0x0001;
  TIM2->CNT = 0;
  NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0);
  tim2_counter = 0;
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  TIM2->SR &= (~0x001F);
  ++tim2_counter;
}

uint32_t get_us(void)
{
  return tim2_counter;
}

void wait_us(volatile uint32_t us)
{
  volatile uint32_t tickstart, now, IRQ_status;
  
  // Get current interrupt status of TIM2 and enable it.
  // Needs to be done with all interrupts disabled to prevent race condition?
  __disable_irq();
  IRQ_status = NVIC_GetEnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
  __enable_irq();
  
  tickstart = get_us();
  now = tickstart;                //<-processing never reaches here under STM32CubeIDE.
  while((now - tickstart) < us)
  {
    now = get_us();
  }
  
  // Return to previous interrupt status of TIM2.
  // Needs to be done with all interrupts disabled to prevent race condition?
  __disable_irq();
  if(0 == IRQ_status)
  {
    NVIC_DisableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
  }
  else
  {
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
  }
  __enable_irq();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add the `volatile` qualifier to `tim2_counter` ?

Comment: There is no change when I qualify `tim2_counter` as volatile.

Comment: What about the other three variables at the top of your `wait_us` function?

Comment: Is `tim2_counter` actually incrementing as expected? If not, you'll just spin forever. I'd run it in the debugger and step through `wait_us()`, looking at all relevant variables.

Comment: There is no change when I qualify the three variables at the top of `wait_us()` as `volatile`.

Comment: When I pause execution after the program gets stuck, the program is often found to be in `TIM2_IRQHandler()`.  If I then step through `TIM2_IRQHandler()` the instruction `++tim2_counter` is executed.

Comment: Looks like you have a data race accessing `tim2_counter`, then. You'll likely need some sort of mutex or other thread-safety mechanism. IRQ handlers are tricksy wee beasts.

Comment: You are generating an interrupt every microsecond. It seems likely that you are just spending all your time in the ISR. Better would be to set `ARR` as high as it can go, and monitor `TIM2->CNT` to measure microseconds. i.e. don't use interrupts at all.

Comment: Obviously to do that, configure the prescaler so that each tick of TIM2 is one microsecond. This will depend on how you have configured the clocks.

Comment: @Adrian Mole STM32CubeIDE wouldn't recognize the functions from <pthread.h> so I simply set a flag in the ISR to show that the interrupt was being serviced, and did a busy wait on that flag in `get_us()`.  With this modification the program ran successfully.  But why did it run under Keil uVision even without this modification?

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't see a data race with your original code (once you added `volatile` to `tim2_counter`), nor do I understand why adding a busy wait flag would make any difference. Can you (or @AdrianMole) explain the exact failure mechanism? (Maybe in an answer, if appropriate?)